# Python Django HTMLCalendar How To Set First Weekday To Sunday

Tags: python, html, django, calendar

Like title states goal is to get the weeks in the calendar to lead with Sunday as opposed to Monday like the below shows. I know `calendar.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)` should be able to do the trick here. I just can't figure out how/where to add it in this code or if there's a different method needed. Won't waste your time with the dumb things I've tried to get Sunday to lead the week in the calendar.

[image]

Current Code That Displays Monday Week Start:

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None, group=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.group = group
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    def formatday(self, day):
        d = ''
        if day != 0:
            return f"<td name='date-event-input' id={date(year=self.year, month=self.month, day=day)}><span " \
                   f"class='date'>{day}</span><ul>{d}</ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'

    def formatweek(self, theweek):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d)

        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar" id="calendar-table-id">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week)}\n'

        return cal
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it just after creating an instance of your custom calendar class. It should work.
I mean;

```
# Create an instance of your custom calendar class
my_calendar = Calendar()


# Set the first weekday to Sunday
calendar.setfirstweekday(6)
```

Comment: So that didn't work but modifying an instance of custom Calendar class just after creating it did work! So right below `my_calendar = Calendar()` I added `my_calendar.setfirstweekday(6)` and that did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in right direction. If you modify your answer accordingly I'll accept it.